# Work Items not appearing in Iteration even when Iteration Path appears to be set

Tags: iteration, azure-boards

Despite apparently successfully assigning a feature to a Release (parent) level iteration the Iteration is still showing as having no work scheduled.

I have created a simple structure to help me understand how best to use ADO to manage my backlog.   I have a two (three including the project level) iteration hierarchy to represent Releases and Sprints.    I have two levels of teams.  One to represent the Planning/PO team and one for deliver/scrum teams.  I have subscribed the dev teams to the Sprint level iterations and I can successfully assign PBIs to the sprints.

However, I want to be able to assign features to releaeses.   I have subscribed the Planning team to the release level iterations and have a Feature Level backlog.   The iterations are showing up on the Planning section and I can assign features (I've tried drag and drop, Updating via the list and detail form - all APPEAR to work).   I even get a message to say they have been successfully assigned when I drag and drop.  However the iterations still say there is no work scheduled yet and if I open the iteration it shows nothing.

The following shot shows the Iteration Path is set but the corresponding Iterations are displayed as empty.

Backlog View

[image: 1]

Looking at the individual feature and querying on the iteration path also suggests the path is set correctly so I can't understand why the iterations appear empty.

Any ideas why?  I've seen some suggestion it is because of the work item type but I pretty much followed the video here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/?view=azure-devops

TIA

Comment: After another look and a bit more investigation I think I have discovered that I can't really do what I want.   As far as I can tell, despite being able to set the Iteration path for a feature only Backlog Items and Bugs show up in the iteration itself.  I'm still not sure how in the video above the higher order iterations have contents - I guess there is some sort of roll up set from the sprints that I don't have set.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Were you able to make it work? I am doing exact same, and have exact same issue. Wonder if some how iteration path is restricted to not show features somewhere in the project setting